# Pass user as parameter

Tags: django, python-3.x, url

I have field in view:
 `<h1>{{article.author}}</h1>`

And I want pass author to UR:

```
 <p><a href="{% url 'subscribe' user=article.author %}">Подписаться на пользователя {{article.author}}</a> </p>
```

URL:

```
  path('<user:user>',views.sunscribe, name="subscribe")
```

But I have error:

> "URL route '%s' uses invalid converter %s." % (original_route, e)
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: URL route '' uses invalid converter 'user'.

Comment: You can not pass a `user` as parameter (you can define a path converter to pass some sort of encoding, as is explained here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters), but by default you can only pass `int`,s, `str`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**In short**: you can not pass a `User` object as parameter, you can pass an *encoding* of (a reference to) a `User`, but this is typically a security risk, and will probably not make life easier than just passing the `id`.

It is possible that the [*path converters* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) give a false impression, but you can *not* simply parse all sorts of objects. By default (on the moment of writing), there are only five path converters: `str`, `int`, `slug`, `uuid` and `path`.

So you will have to find an "encoding" to pass a reference to the object. The most straightforward way is probably the primary key, so you can implement it like:

```
path('<int:user_id>',views.sunscribe, name="subscribe")
```

and in the template use it like:

```
<p>
  <a href="{% url 'subscribe' user=article.author.id %}">
    Подписаться на пользователя {{article.author}}
  </a>
</p>
```

In that case you thus obtain the `id` of the `user`, and you will need to fetch the `user` object.

The documentation also mentions how you can write [path conversions yourself [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters). But still you will pass a *representation* of the object (you could, as really bad solution generate for example a pickle stream, but that would be very unsafe, since it would probably impose a severe security risk).

An URL can only contain *text*, *not* objects. So even if you write a custom path conversion, you still will need some sort of encoding and decoding.

You can of course ease the process a bit, by making a path converter, that makes the process of generating an `id` and retrieving the `id` transparent, by writing a custom path converter, like:

```
from django.urls.converters import IntConverter

class UserConverter:

    def to_python(self, value):
        return User.object.get(pk=value)

    def to_url(self, value):
        return value.pk

register_converter(converters.UserConverter, 'user')
```

This will then make the process more transparent, then you can use indeed `{% url 'subscribe' user=article.author %}`, and `<user:user>` in the `path(..)` definition. But I do not know if this improves the situation a lot.